# Scared + Worried

Tags: word-request, adjectives

My friend says she felt a way about doing something and can't explain the feeling. I asked if it was scared and sad mixed together and of course, she said yes.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. Is your question: _What is a word in English which means both "scared" and "sad," or "scared" and "worried?"_

Answer (score 1):

If your friend is scared and a worried, it could be said she is feeling  apprehensive.

Example:
My friend is apprehensive about getting together again with her ex-boyfriend.

A synonym of apprehensive is the word "dread."

Example: 
I dread going to the dentist.

People who suffer from depression and anxiety often describe having a sense of "impending doom."

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your answer. It might be even better if you can provide a link to a dictionary definition of _apprehension. Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will answer miore questions, and ask some of your own!

Comment: What about **scared**?

Answer (score 1):

You initially mentioned scared and worried then added sad in the context of your post.

I would say all 2 have similar meaning and the 3rd being a result of the other 2 feelings.

For instance, scared - simply implies fear of a situation.

Worried is uncertainty from a concern over a known or unknown situation.

In this case sad would be the depressed emotion that the 2 other feelings gave her.

Examples:
I am scared my dad is going to discipline me for not doing my chores. ( known situation )

My dad said he would be home by 10 and it is now 12. I am worried something may have happened to him. ( uncertainty )

Not knowing if my dad is ok, has me feeling sad. ( result feeling of something known or unknown )